# Table width does not fit the textwidth after using \newcolumntype in tabularx environment!

Tags: tabularx, textwidth

I use the tabularx package and use \newcolumntype command to specify the column width.

However, the text width of the table does not fit the text width of the document after I use the specified column type, i.e., *s* in the example.

And if I don't use the specified column type, the text with of the table is correct.

The source code and the output PDF is showed as follows,

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.23\hsize}X}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table*}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{Table example.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lslX}
        \hline
        column1 & column2   &column3    &column4\\
        \hline
        abc & some text & some text in column3 &some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        aaa &bbbbb  &ccccc  &dddddd\\
        bcd & some text in column2  & some text in column3 & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{Table example.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
        \hline
        column1 & column2   &column3    &column4\\
        \hline
        abc & some text & some text in column3 &some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        aaa &bbbbb  &ccccc  &dddddd\\
        bcd & some text in column2  & some text in column3 & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: illustration of output]

How to make TABLE 1 display as TABLE 2, i.e., the text in the table 1 fit the whole text width of the document?

Comment: `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.23\hsize}X}` will completely break the tabularx algorithm to determine column widths.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, how to specify the width of a column correctly?

Comment: The sum of the coefficients of `\hsize` in the `X` columns has to be the total number of columns. It seems you try to obtain a certain ratio between the `s` column type and the `X` column type, if I'm not mistaken, but I'm not sure which it is. Could you give details?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, exactly. And I think I have got your idea. For example, if `s` is set to be `0.23\hsize` as above, then the last column should be `1.77\hsize` to ensure the sum to be `2X`. 
The code should be like 
`\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.4\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X}
`
then 
`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lslL}`
will work correctly.

Comment: Yes. The last code says the `s`  column is ¼ of the `L` column. It's a sort of barycentric coordinates which is used.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sveinung Have done. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: @Sveinung have clicked it, but it said that I can only accept my own answer in 2 days.

Comment: I was not aware of that limitation. Sorry. I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution.

As indicated by @Bernard

> The sum of the coefficients of \hsize in the X columns has to be the
>   total number of columns.

So the code should be like：

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{Table example.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l >{\hsize=.23\hsize}X l >{\hsize=1.77\hsize}X}
        \hline
        column1 & column2   &column3    &column4\\
        \hline
        abc & some text & some text in column3 &some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        aaa &bbbbb  &ccccc  &dddddd\\
        bcd & some text in column2  & some text in column3 & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\begin{table*}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{Table example.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
        \hline
        column1 & column2   &column3    &column4\\
        \hline
        abc & some text & some text in column3 &some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        aaa &bbbbb  &ccccc  &dddddd\\
        bcd & some text in column2  & some text in column3 & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Then the following output is obtained：
[image]